# not enough server storage is available to process this command in windows xp while accessing mapped drive from windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, mapped-drive

I am facing strange problem that when windows XP user try to access mapped drive mapped from Windows 7 he received error as "not enough server storage is available to process this command" i have changed registry entry and group policy detail also but still getting the same error but only work fine when i restart the server service from windows 7 but after sometime the same things happen so need to restart the server service again and again.

Only users with Windows XP face this problem while other windows 7 users are working fine and using workgroup environment.

I need permanent solution,

Thanks in advance for the same.

Comment: Only user with Windows XP face this problem while other window7 user working fine and using workgroup environment

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you install any software on XP that installs filter drivers. The problem is that XP's Lanman Server has a fixed
limit on how many filters it will support. This was fixed in later versions of Windows.

Try this

In XP Click Start, and then click Run.
Type regedit and then click OK.
Navigate to the following key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters

In the right pane, delete the value IRPStackSize. If you
delete this value Lanman Server will not have any limits.

Close the Registry Editor.

Restart the computer.

Comment: Have already checked it but there is not any value present in registry name as IRPStaclSize

Comment: Try creating the IRPStackSize dword and give it a values of 25, restart the PC.

Comment: Have done the same but still the same problem continue

Comment: Even windows 7 machine from where files store and share have 24 gb of ram and no on login on that pc as we are using it as file server

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the problem for me without requiring a reboot:

from admin cmd prompt on server:
`net stop server`
enter y for all confirmations
`net stop srvnet`
enter y for all confirmations
`net start srvnet`
`net start server`